# How autofill 2fa from sms works in chrome on ios

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome

I have problem with autofill one-time-code inputs from `2fa` sms. First I should explain that I have one separate input for each single sms code, each input has set `autocomplete = one-time-password`. I've tested autofill on `safari` and works fine there is only chrome problem on mobile.

In `Chrome` when I want to autofill inputs from sms code only fill first input. Could someone explain me who autofill works on chrome ? I've debugged this on safari and there after click autofill on each input is fires on change event.

If someone has similar problem or know who chrome behaves on autofill, please help me.